# Clipping users cursor around the X button

Tags: c++, delphi

This should be simple, and I was hoping to do it in Delphi.
The purpose of this is just supposed to be a joke.

On a windows form application I don't want the user to be able to click the X button on the main form.  I want the cursor to either clip around the X button or just set it's position elsewhere.

Comment: Is there some way to do this for ALL windows?

Comment: How about changing the FormStyle so you don't have the X to begin with.

Comment: @Robert: then there wouldn't be a joke to start with...

Comment: Making an app that acts like this is evil, but maybe fun as a joke. Making all apps behave like this is not even fun! Anyway, I am not even sure if it is readily doable. A single application is not to alter the behaviour of other apps, at least not in "unreasonable" ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure NcMouseMove(var Message: TWMNCMouseMove); message WM_NCMOUSEMOVE;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure TForm1.NcMouseMove(var Message: TWMNCMouseMove);
begin
  inherited;
  with Message do
    if HitTest = HTCLOSE then
      SetCursorPos(XCursor + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMENUSIZE), YCursor)
end;
```